# How to Voice Chat in Kopete for Google Talk contacts

Tags: 11.04, kubuntu, kopete

I am on Kubuntu 11.04. I have set up my google talk account in Kopete as per normal setup (talk.google.com-5223-SSL).

But the problem is I can't seem to find the call option for voice calls. As per I recall when last I used Kubuntu (10.10), there was an option to talk with google contacts. It was possible via kopete-gcall. But Kopete-gcall seems to be missing in Natty.

It's a very useful feature to talk to google contacts from Kopete. Is it me only or others have been facing this issue as well?

Need your help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

From Kopete's handbook,

> "*Since Google Talk is based upon
>   Jabber, it is well supported in Kopete
>   **with the exception of voice chat**, which is worked upon.*"

Comment: Thanks Cyborg. If you are referring to this link at handbook : http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdenetwork/kopete/protocols.html, then I think it's old info. Kopete handbook (http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdenetwork/kopete/) last revision date shows "Revision 0.12 (2006-12-15)". As per last I used Kopete (19.10), voice chat was working. It may be that on Natty this feature is not there presently. Would love to get some info about when we can get back the voice chat feature at Kopete.

Comment: It's from the handbook accessed by the current version (Version 1.0.80) I have installed. I haven't tried voicechat, but the webcam (in configure) works. If you want to test it, my gmail address is on my profile.